# Retreive column names from the table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have the follwing table, using sqlalchemy

```
Class student():
__tablename__ : 'student'
__table_args__: {'schema' : 'schooldb'}

name = Column(name='Name')
Id = Column (name= 'roll no', primarykey='true')
```

I tried

```
r = session.query.(student).filterby()
r.column_descriptions
```

How to retrieve only the column names in such orm model?

Comment: `column_names = [c.name for c in student.__table__.columns]`

Comment: .__table__ is not showing up as option instead __tablename__ comes what other way?

Comment: If you mean "not showing up" when you invoke code completion in your IDE then that doesn't necessarily mean that the attribute does not exist. (It doesn't show up in PyCharm for me, either, but it *does* exist.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.